# How do you Swap details in columns from one ID to another ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have 3 tables, the person table, the organisation table and the link table 
called PersonOrganisation with PersonId and Organisation keys. I want to 
swap two people between two organisations after the User inputs the Id's of the two people he wants to switch.
Example: I enter **2** and **6** for the **PersonId's** 
and then the **organisation associated with person 2** is swapped with **organisation associated with person 6**.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: There are several parts to that requirement - which part are you stuck on?  Capturing the input?  Generating the SQL statement?  What have you tried so far?  Hint:  All you need is two updates to the link table.

Comment: Stack isn't about writing the logic for you.  Instead we offer assistance when you encounter a problem with specific code.  Please show some work and where you're having trouble; we'd be happy to assist.

Comment: Why do you have a separate table for `PersonOrganization`, if a person only has one organization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
update PersonOrganization
    set PersonId = (case when PersonId = 2 then 6 else 2 end)
    where (PersonId in (2, 6);
```

In other words, swap the persons, not the organizations.